# Lumen of Laravel & OAuth2 - grant type: Client Credentials working but how to use Username/Password Approach correctly

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, oauth-2.0, lumen

I am using Lumen and [OAuth2-Server-Laravel by lucadegasperi](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/wiki/Implementing-an-Authorization-Server-With-the-Client-Credentials-Grant)

I have successfully set up Client Credentials and on Postman I can post:

`grant_type - client_credentials`,
`client_id - id1`
`client_secret - secret1` and receiving success (200):

> `{"access_token":"jiKaracRLX1fOR0Ls3w7aE7G5ukblFIkkB2jwBGw","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600}` as response.

... but I totally got lost at this point. What should I do to add username/password approach with OAuth2?

I found [Password Grant Type](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/wiki/Implementing-an-Authorization-Server-with-the-Password-Grant) in the docs, but I couldn't figure out what to do next. Do I need to create another migration table - users? If so, how will I be able to validate the variables passed? I got confused because it also will require `client_id` and `client_secret` from me.

Or am I supposed to receive `username` and `password` variables in function with a post request, and before verifying `username` and `password` in the controller, with using Guzzle, I should verify `client_id` and `client_secret` separately, and if `access_token` is true, continue on logging in. Is that approach right?

Answer (score 0):

I was with this problem too.

You can use this configuration:
https://github.com/dusterio/lumen-passport#configuration

And your model "User" need this:

```
use Laravel\Lumen\Auth\Authorizable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    use HasApiTokens, Authenticatable, Authorizable;

    /** functions */
}
```

Explaining: After performing the configuration and executing the passport migrations you will see that in the oauth_clients table two records are generated, note that one record has the column personal_access_client selected and the other record has the column password_client selected.

The record that has the personal_access_client selected will use the corresponding secret for grant_type = client_credentials. This is will return a bearer token for an application.

The record that has the password_client selected you will use the corresponding secret for grant_type = password. This is will return a bearer token for an user (you need send username and password too).

You don't need to do anything in the User model other than what I explained above because passport will do the rest on its own.

After condigured and your tests is working, you need include the middlware auth to leave the application work alone. It is necessary to include the token in the request header for these routes.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function () 
{
    Route::post('authenticated_test', 'AuthController@routeAuthenticatedTest');
});
```